# Running VSCode from Ubuntu WSL2 not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to run VSCode in my Ubuntu WSL2.

When I run `code .` , zsh is unable to find VSCode.
I have installed **Remote - WSL** plugin in VSCode, and I am able to open my Ubuntu Instance from Windows. I want to achieve it from Ubuntu terminal as well.

```
ayman@DESKTOP  ~  code .
zsh: command not found: code
```

I have tried `wsl --shutdown` and then reinstalling Remote-WSL plugin, but it still does not work.

Is there a `zsh` configuration required for running VSCode from terminal? If so, what are the configurations required?

Answer (score 5):

If VSCode is in your Windows path, it should be in your WSL path as well.  Things to check:

- Is VSCode in your Windows path?  If not, add it there first.
- Windows path propagation to WSL is enabled by default, but double-check that.  Check to see if there's a line there in the `[interop]` section named `appendWindowsPath`.  If it is set to `false`, change it to `true` or just delete the line altogether.
- Perhaps your startup scripts (e.g. `~/.zshrc`) are modifying the path (or setting a new one entirely)?  If so, append to the path in your startup scripts rather than replacing it.
- Any zsh extensions that could be modifying the path?

Comment: Definitely worth checking your ~/.zshrc (or .bashrc in my case), in case a helpful Anaconda installer has removed the Windows path from the WSL path. At least it added a comment to highlight what it had done:).